# Plotting 3D scatter with python?

Tags: python, 3d

[image]

Is there any module that could aid me in producing something like this?

Comment: These are not **density** plots, they're **scatter** plots (as you can tell by the method name in the accepted answer). I'm looking to make 3D density plots which is how I ended up here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.html), say?

[image: matplotlib 3D scatter plot]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_images/scatter3d_demo.png))</sub>

The [`matplotlib` examples gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) is a wonderful thing to behold.

---

Code copied from the linked example.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    return (vmax-vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
n = 100
for c, m, zl, zh in [('r', 'o', -50, -25), ('b', '^', -30, -5)]:
    xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
    ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
    zs = randrange(n, zl, zh)
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=c, marker=m)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Very nice answer, that should help him out :-)

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from the [Cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/mplot3D)

```
from numpy import *
import pylab as p
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3

x=random.randn(100)
y=random.randn(100)
z=random.randn(100)

fig=p.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter3D(ravel(x),ravel(y),ravel(z))
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
p.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html) should be able to do something like that.